# Extract multiple fields from clob

Tags: oracle, substr, clob

I have a oracle database with a clob field. The data in the field looks like this (this is data from 1 row in the clob);

```
outputLocale;runOptionEnum;runOptionLanguageArray;123;<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="xsd:string">en-us</item>{CR}{LF}
</value>{CR}{LF}
ccAddress;deliveryOptionEnum;deliveryOptionAddressSMTPArray;207;<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:addressSMTP[2]">{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">bccesa@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">blah@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
</value>{CR}{LF}
toAddress;deliveryOptionEnum;deliveryOptionAddressSMTPArray;271;<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:addressSMTP[3]">{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa2017@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa2018@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa9@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
</value>{CR}{LF}
```

I need to extract the email addresses as a single line, so the prefered output would be bccesa@blah.nl, blah@blah.nl, esa2017@blah.nl, esa2018@blah.nl, esa9@blah.nl etc.. some rows have 1 email address and others have 10.

I have tried to first locating the field using substr and instr functions, but I think there is a easier way to do this. The data might looks like XML but in the end it's not.. so the xml oracle options don't seem to work.

Comment: Strip out `{CR}{LF}` and the `;` separated strings before the `<value>` elements. Then it looks like you should be able to process it as XML.

Comment: Maybe, but stripping out those fields is not as easy as it sounds.. since the outputLocale;runOptionEnum;runOptionLanguageArray;123 part has a variable length in the clob..

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( clob_field, '(^|</value>).*?($|<value)|\{cr\}\{lf\}', '\1\2' ) FROM table_name;` should strip it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but your code doesn't seem to make any change to the output. Is there a way to search and only show the field between <item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa2017@blah.nl</item> ?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text in a XML element and then just parse it as XML:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INT, clob_field CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name (
  id, clob_field
) VALUES (
  1, 'outputLocale;runOptionEnum;runOptionLanguageArray;123;<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="xsd:string">en-us</item>{CR}{LF}
</value>{CR}{LF}
ccAddress;deliveryOptionEnum;deliveryOptionAddressSMTPArray;207;<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:addressSMTP[2]">{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">bccesa@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">blah@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
</value>{CR}{LF}
toAddress;deliveryOptionEnum;deliveryOptionAddressSMTPArray;271;<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:addressSMTP[3]">{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa2017@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa2018@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
{>>}<item xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP">esa9@blah.nl</item>{CR}{LF}
</value>{CR}{LF}'
);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.id,
       LISTAGG( x.address, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS addresses
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/SOAP-ENC/value/item[@xsi:type="bus:addressSMTP"]'
         PASSING XMLType(
           '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENC xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'
           || t.clob_field
           || '</SOAP-ENC>'
         )
         COLUMNS address VARCHAR2(200) PATH 'text()'
       ) x
GROUP BY t.id;
```

**Output**:

```
ID ADDRESSES
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 bccesa@blah.nl,blah@blah.nl,esa2017@blah.nl,esa2018@blah.nl,esa9@blah.nl
```

Comment: Excellent.. worked straight out of the box! From this I can continue!